# Body/HTML elements shrink to be much smaller than viewport

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I'm in the process of making my wordpress website responsive. I have two images on the page I'm working on which I want to set a `max-width` on of 100% to make them responsive (this is what I did on another website I made and it worked beautifully). However, I have noticed that as I shrink the page in Chrome dev tools the `<html>` and `<body>` elements are shrinking to really odd sizes, completely unrelated to the viewport size. Below are screenshots of the  and  elements, respectively, being hovered over in chrome dev tools:

[image: html]   [image: body]

And, of course since `max-width` with a percentage value, "Defines the maximum width of the containing block" and the containing blocks here (`<html>` and `body`) are resizing themselves in this unusual way, when I set the images to `max-width: 100%` they base that off the weird size of those elements.

The only CSS I have on these elements is:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

So my question is, where on earth are the `<html>` and `<body>` elements getting their size from?

Answer (score 3):

This behavior first began happening a few versions ago in Chrome; try testing your site/screens using FF (Moz/Firefox) responsive dev tools -- my guess is you'll see the results you expect. But this isn't necessarily an issue with Chrome; in my case it has something to do with environment. These days I work mostly with AEM and if I test in auth mode/disabled (or straight-up auth mode) this issue will occur. But if I view the same page live in production = no issue. So my guess (for us at least) is that it has something to do with the CMS or the server setup. I tend to use FF responsive dev tools these days -- give that a try and let us know how you make out.

Comment: Thank you Bob. I will try this! Will let you know the results!

Comment: Hey @Bob you're totally right! I tried it in FF and I'm not getting that weird behaviour. So, are you suggesting that the Wordpress dev environment might be the cause of this? I was wondering if that could be the case, because the CSS for this project is very similar to (if not simpler) an old website I made which is 100% responsive and works perfectly in Chrome and the only difference between the two is that this one is in WP.

Comment: This happened to me when I added the meta tag `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">` in the header to support media queries.

Comment: This also happens to me after all those years on Chrome and not Firefox. Chrome on actual mobile device and the mobile emulator of the desktop both have this.

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: Its best to explain why your answer works

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that your zoom level is set to 100% (normal), in your browser.

Comment: @maxine-ellah - Hey, did this solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I just manage to fix the same issue.
The problem is that the text forces the viewport width. You just have to ajust the font size to fix the issue.