# Changing font-size of html element for scaling rem unit

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Is it good practise to change the font-size of html element with media queries for achieving responsive design?

I think it is breaking the layout for smaller sizes similar to this question: [Body/HTML elements shrink to be much smaller than viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713274/body-html-elements-shrink-to-be-much-smaller-than-viewport). Not sure about this.

Comment: I am struggling to understand what 'correct' would mean here in a general case - there are so many possible scenarios. Sometimes it might be OK to make the font size smaller for example so that things fit nicely, sometimes this won't be suitable because the font size will render the text unreadable if it gets too small. etc etc.

Comment: Don't overthink this too much. Does the page you are working on require you to change the font-size with a media query? Well, then that's the way to go...

My CSS default is always `html { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) }`. Smoothly sizes the document base font size  between `14px` and `20px` depending on the current minimum viewport size. All other sizes of any element in my pages are in `REM`, root dependent. I only use `EM` when I really need parent dependecy. No media query required. Optionally `clamp(0.875rem,  calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem), 1.25rem)`, if you must...